# What happens if I use mongos 2.6 with mongod 3.0

Tags: mongodb, sharding

**Scope:**

I'm currently upgrading a large MongoDB sharded environment from 2.6 to 3.0, following the recommendations provided by the official documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#upgrade-recommendations-and-checklists

In it, they warning us with the following note:

> Do not upgrade the mongod instances until after you have upgraded all
>   the mongos instances.

However, they don't tell us what are the consequences of doing so, and more important, how to recover the situation if it happens.

**Goal:**

We want to test a mongos 2.6 connecting to a 3.0 sharded environment and simulate its troubleshooting.

**Question:**

Before to proceed (obviously in a testing environment), I'd like to know if anyone has done such test and what were the results. In addition, how did you recover the situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the above and seemly the mongod just doesn't allow to mongos to establish the connection:

```
mongos> show tables
2016-10-17T13:24:00.954+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
       "$err" : "could not initialize sharding on connection mtk-uat-rs-eu0/mongod.mtkdb413.motortrak.com:28100,mongod.mtkdb413.motortrak.com:28101 :: caused by :: v3.0 mongod is incompatible with v2.6 mongos, a v2.6 mongos may be running in the v3.0 cluster at 192.168.151.28",
       "code" : 15907,
       "shard" : "mtk-uat-rs-eu0"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBQuery.prototype.next@src/mongo/shell/query.js:297:1
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosSystemNamespaces@src/mongo/shell/db.js:743:27
DB.prototype.getCollectionInfos@src/mongo/shell/db.js:789:16
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:796:16
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:753:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:650:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1

mongos> show tables
2016-10-17T14:20:24.223+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
       "$err" : "could not initialize sharding on connection mtk-uat-rs-eu0/mongod.mtkdb413.motortrak.com:28100,mongod.mtkdb413.motortrak.com:28101 :: caused by :: v3.0 mongod is incompatible with v2.6 mongos, a v2.6 mongos may be running in the v3.0 cluster at 192.168.151.28",
       "code" : 15907,
       "shard" : "mtk-uat-rs-eu0"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBQuery.prototype.next@src/mongo/shell/query.js:297:1
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosSystemNamespaces@src/mongo/shell/db.js:743:27
DB.prototype.getCollectionInfos@src/mongo/shell/db.js:789:16
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:796:16
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:753:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:650:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```